# implementation idea of store database

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I have a MySQL database. One of the tables is `PRODUCTS`. One product in the shop can contain many options like tax, size, price, colour, description, etc. All attributes are saved in other tables because they can be modified by administrator. So if a customer buys a product then all the information about the product will saved in the `ORDERS` table. What happens when the admin changes a product's price or tax value, or possible size of the items? I need to keep all rows that were in the table tax, colour, size but all with data column when these options was available? Which column should be used to combine all of the tables?

Comment: Why you can't save in ORDERS only product_id, the foreign key for other tables with price, tax, size, etc. With this key you always obtain actual information about the order.

Comment: Because when I save in the ORDERS table product ID = 1 and the price of product was 3$ and admin changed the price for 4$ then in history of orders will be that the client buy product for 4$. It's only simple example.

Comment: OK, so you can add in ORDERS as many columns as tables you have to store options. If there are too many columns or some of them are not used, you can pack options into some structured format, like JSON or XML and store it in one TEXT column. What about this solution?

Comment: It must be better solution. Imagine that product contain 25 options that are optional. Some of them are deleted, updated. In your way if I will saved attributes in ORDER then I will have additional 25 columns in ORDER table. It's not great idea. About JSON or XML in TEXT column there is problem with filtering. I cannot search the products via SQL command where tax was 18%, price $4 and colour is Red because all is in TEXT field.

Comment: You can combine: fixed columns for mandatory parameters (price, for example) and TEXT column for options. I didn't use but there is a library with set of json-related functions: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json : you can search and modify values, but can't index them. Anyway, I also want to see a better solution :) Using MySQL for post-order analisys is the strict condition?

Comment: Database will not be in First normal form 1FN. Each attribute not contains only atomic values. Everything should be easy in managed and I want to execute various form of SQL statements on optional fields e.g. ORDER BY, LIMIT...

Comment: Another decision: add two timestamp columns: 'from' and 'to' into the each options tables which mean that this property (option) was valid in specified time period. Using timestamp column in ORDERS table you can obtain all historical values of any options.

Comment: I also thought about it and it's probably the best solution. But now I have to check what is the best method of combination all tables into one. Do you have any idea? foreign key + additional clause WHERE with date range?

Comment: I added to the datetime column for optionals tables. And at the time of join ORDER table with other tables. I use 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' with foreign key comparison and additionally I check date range using subquery e.g. `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p LEFT OUTER JOIN TAX t ON p.tax_id = t.id  AND p.data = (SELECT max(data) FROM TAX WHERE data < p.data )`. Now I have to check efficiency of this query in combination maybe of 10 tables.